# A lot of requests android

Tags: android, request, android-volley

I have an android and a certain Activity need be checking whether a database record has changed, it has to do something, it does not continue checking.

I checked several ways to do this, one is creating a service and make requests to Volley in my RESTful server, for example, every 5 minutes. This is impossible since the server will receive thousands of requests per minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done from the backend, I believe. By using Push notification (GCM) or http pulling, whenever any data has been changed on the database, it will send an message to the client, client will respond based on that.Waiting to hear from somebody who is really master on those things. Thanks and best of luck

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, I've developed it using GCM in the backend and it worked!